# "Run-time error '1004' " when using FormulaR1C1?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a template for a process route card for our factory, which configures itself based on a few inputs. One section of this is a build log for serialised parts.

I want to insert this formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(RIGHT(K122,4)+1< $E$17+1, IF(AND(MID(K122,23,1)="0",NOT(RIGHT(K122,1)="9")),CONCAT(LEFT(K122,(LEN(K122)-4)),IF(LEN(RIGHT(K122,4)+1)=1,CONCAT("000",RIGHT(K122,4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(K122,4)+1)=2,CONCAT("00",RIGHT(K122,4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(K122,4)+1)=3,CONCAT("0",RIGHT(K122,4)+1),RIGHT(K122,4)+1)))),IF(AND(MID(K122,22,1)="0",NOT(MID(K122,23,2)="99")),CONCAT(LEFT(K122,(LEN(K122)-4)),IF(LEN(RIGHT(K122,4)+1)=1,CONCAT("000",RIGHT(K122,4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(K122,4)+1)=2,CONCAT("00",RIGHT(K122,4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(K122,4)+1)=3,CONCAT("0",RIGHT(K122,4)+1),RIGHT(K122,4)+1)))),IF(AND(MID(K122,21,1)="0",NOT(MID(K122,22,3)="999")),CONCAT(LEFT(K122,(LEN(K122)-4)),IF(LEN(RIGHT(K122,4)+1)=1,CONCAT("000",RIGHT(K122,4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(K122,4)+1)=2,CONCAT("00",RIGHT(K122,4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(K122,4)+1)=3,CONCAT("0",RIGHT(K122,4)+1),RIGHT(K122,4)+1)))),CONCAT(LEFT(K122,(LEN(K122)-4)),IF(LEN(RIGHT(K122,4)+1)=1,CONCAT("000",RIGHT(K122,4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(K122,4)+1)=2,CONCAT("00",RIGHT(K122,4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(K122,4)+1)=3,CONCAT("0",RIGHT(K122,4)+1),RIGHT(K122,4)+1))))))),""),"")
```

in many cells, using R1C1 notation, due to the varying absolute position in the spreadsheet of the structure this formula is a part of.  This formula works.

Converting this formula to R1C1 notation I get:

```
=IFERROR(IF(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1< $E$17+1, IF(AND(MID(R[-2]C[0],23,1)=""0"",NOT(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],1)=""9"")),CONCAT(LEFT(R[-2]C[0],(LEN(R[-2]C[0])-4)),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=1,CONCAT(""000"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=2,CONCAT(""00"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=3,CONCAT(""0"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)))),IF(AND(MID(R[-2]C[0],22,1)=""0"",NOT(MID(R[-2]C[0],23,2)=""99"")),CONCAT(LEFT(R[-2]C[0],(LEN(R[-2]C[0])-4)),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=1,CONCAT(""000"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=2,CONCAT(""00"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=3,CONCAT(""0"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)))),IF(AND(MID(R[-2]C[0],21,1)=""0"",NOT(MID(R[-2]C[0],22,3)=""999"")),CONCAT(LEFT(R[-2]C[0],(LEN(R[-2]C[0])-4)),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=1,CONCAT(""000"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=2,CONCAT(""00"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=3,CONCAT(""0"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)))),CONCAT(LEFT(R[-2]C[0],(LEN(R[-2]C[0])-4)),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=1,CONCAT(""000"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=2,CONCAT(""00"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=3,CONCAT(""0"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1))))))),""""),"""")
```

Inserting into my VBA gave me an error, as my line of code was too long, so I split the text string in two, declared them as constants, and implemented it as so:

```
Private Const Formula1 As String = "=IFERROR(IF(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1< $E$17+1, IF(AND(MID(R[-2]C[0],23,1)=""0"",NOT(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],1)=""9"")),CONCAT(LEFT(R[-2]C[0],(LEN(R[-2]C[0])-4)),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=1,CONCAT(""000"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=2,CONCAT(""00"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=3,CONCAT(""0"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)))),IF(AND(MID(R[-2]C[0],22,1)=""0"",NOT(MID(R[-2]C[0],23,2)=""99"")),CONCAT(LEFT(R[-2]C[0],(LEN(R[-2]C[0])-4)),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=1,CONCAT(""000"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=2,CONCAT(""00"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=3,CONCAT(""0"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)))),IF(AND(MID(R[-2]C[0],21,1)=""0"",NOT(MID(R[-2]C[0],22,3)=""999"")),CONCAT(LEFT(R[-2]C[0],(LEN(R[-2]C[0])-4)),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=1,CONCAT(""000"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=2,CONCAT(""00"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),"
Private Const Formula2 As String = "IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=3,CONCAT(""0"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)))),CONCAT(LEFT(R[-2]C[0],(LEN(R[-2]C[0])-4)),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=1,CONCAT(""000"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=2,CONCAT(""00"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),IF(LEN(RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1)=3,CONCAT(""0"",RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1),RIGHT(R[-2]C[0],4)+1))))))),""""),"""")"
```

```vb
Sub BuildBuildLog()
    RemoveBuildLog
    With Sheets(WSPRC)
        count = 1
        
        For i = 1 To PRCLength ' incrementing rows in the documents
            If InStr(1, LCase(.Cells(i, 1).Value), "blhead01", vbBinaryCompare) Then
                .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            ElseIf InStr(1, LCase(.Cells(i, 1).Value), "blhead02", vbBinaryCompare) Then
                .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            ElseIf InStr(1, LCase(.Cells(i, 1).Value), "blhead03", vbBinaryCompare) Then
                .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                For j = 1 To noHeaders + 1     'counting through the pages of the build log - (+1 to allow for a page for rework log)
                
                    If j > noHeaders Then      'last page of build log is blank - to allow records of reworked assemblies.
                        .Cells(((noHeaders - 1) * 12) + 15, 1).Value = "Rework Log"
                        For k = 1 To 20             'Counting the rows in the build log - 20 per page
                            
                            .Cells(i + k, 1).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                            Call formatBLRow((2 * k) + (i - 1), j)
                        Next k
                    Else
                        For k = 1 To 20             'Counting the rows in the build log - 20 per page
                        
                            If count < batchqty + 1 Then
                                'add a line to the build log
                                If count = 1 Then
                                    .Cells((2 * k) + (i - 1), 12 * j).Formula = "=CONCAT($I$8,"": "",RIGHT($C$7,4),""-"",B31,""-"",E31)"
                                ElseIf k = 1 Then
                                    .Cells((2 * k) + (i - 1), 12 * j).FormulaR1C1 = Formula3 & Formula4
                                Else
                                    .Cells((2 * k) + (i - 1), 12 * j).FormulaR1C1 = Formula1 & Formula2
                                End If
                                
                                Call formatBLRow((2 * k) + (i - 1), j)
                            Else
                                Exit For                'Exit for loop if count of rows in build log is greater or equal to batch quantity
                            End If
                            count = count + 1
                            
                        Next k
                    End If
                Next j
            
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

The error:

> Run-time error '1004'      Application-defined or object-defined error`

occurs the first time formulaR1C1 is called, during the

```vb
For k = 1 To 20             'Counting the rows in the build log - 20 per page count`
```

for loop, for count = 2, k=2.

Although the formula is long, it is shorter than the limit of the length of the property I am trying to insert it into.

Comment: Where do you define formula3 and formula4?

Comment: They are defined in the code aswell, similar to formula1 and formula2.  I didn't post the complete code base, due to it having almost 1000 lines of code at this point xD,

Thanks for taking the time to read I worked out my issue, see below.

Comment: Not the answer to your question: but I would put effort in refactoring the formula - even if you find the issue now, you will struggle next time when you have to make adjustments due to new business requirments ...

Comment: This fomula increment's a serial number based on the previous serial number.  The serial number is string of the format:

`"Partno": nnnn-yyww-xxxx`

where part no can vary in length, nnnn is a job number identifier, yyww - year and week part produced - xxxx is an incremental 4 digit number.

On the face of if this seems like it should be easy to do, but because I am trying to do arithmatic on numbers stored as part of a string, and the string length can not change it turns into a right headache of checking of the length of the xxxx section of the string.

Comment: I guess I should create a custom Forumla "INCREMENTSERIAL", then call it as:  `..formulaR1C1 = " = INCREMENTSERIAL(R[-1]C[0])` , 

Doing all the string manipulation in vba...  it would end up much more readable if I didn't have to do it all inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realised my error.. I didn't fully convert the formula into R1C1 notation, I had left the lone explicit Cell reference in A1 notation

`$E$17`

..Converting that to `R17C5` fixed it.

Sorry for the long read for the elementary issue.

Regards,

Comment: I would seriously consider converting that formula to a UDF.  If someone else had to support this, that formula is going to be a monster to modify.  While a UDF doesn't give you the same performance as built-in, it is normally easier to read, comprehend and modify.

Comment: I did do just that not long after I made this post.  :)